# ChunkList with yield

Tags: c#, list, yield

I have a problem with a List that should be chunked into sublists. I use a yield to do this.
The List has x items and should be chunked by x chunkzizes.
For this example I use a chunkSize of 4 and 18 items in my list.

The Result is 5 Sublists with 4, 4, 4, 4, 2 items.
My question is. Is it possible that the result looks like this 4, 4, 4, 3, 3?
If yes how? :-)
Thanks for your help.

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>
{
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "10",
  "11",
  "12",
  "13",
  "14",
  "15",
  "16",
  "17",
  "18"
};

int chunkSize = 4
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<StapeladministratorListItemModel>> chunkList = ChunkBy(testList, chunkSize);
```

This is my method with my yield return.

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int chunkSize)
{
 while (source.Any())
 {
  yield return source.Take(chunkSize);
  source = source.Skip(chunkSize);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  After each iteration of the list, you will need to check whether there is enough items left in the list to complete an entire chunk.  If not, try and divide the rest of the remaining items in 2, to get sizes smaller than the original chuck value, but equal.  You would need to implement logic for in case the remaining items cannot be divided into 2 equal chunks

Comment: Returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>` is usually a bad thing, as the inner enumerable cannot be run twice. You usually need to return `IEnumerable<TSource[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: we return `chunk` after `chunk` up to the *last two* chunks where we have to decide which chunks' lengths we want to obtain.

I've uses `Queue<TSource>` in order to have *one pass* routine: when we call `source.Take` and then `source.Skip` as you do in your code, there is a possibility that `source` *can be changed* between these calls (if, say, we have `source = File.ReadLines(...)...`).

```
// Let me return IEnumerable<TSource[]>; but you can change it back to
// IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>  
private static IEnumerable<TSource[]> ChunkBy<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                       int chunkSize) {
  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (chunkSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkSize));

  var agenda = new Queue<TSource>();
  
  foreach (TSource item in source) {
    agenda.Enqueue(item);

    if (agenda.Count >= 2 * chunkSize) {
      TSource[] chunk = new TSource[chunkSize];

      for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Length; ++i)
        chunk[i] = agenda.Dequeue();

      yield return chunk;
    }
  }

  if (agenda.Count <= chunkSize)
    yield return agenda.ToArray();
  else {
    //TODO: here you should decide how to split the two last chunks
    // I divide by 2; if agenda.Count is odd the first chunk will be longer
    yield return agenda.Take((agenda.Count + 1) / 2).ToArray();
    yield return agenda.Skip((agenda.Count + 1) / 2).ToArray();
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  IList<string> testList = new List<string> { 
     "1",   "2",   "3",   "4",
     "5",   "6",   "7",   "8",
     "9",  "10",  "11",  "12",
    "13",  "14",  "15",  "16",
    "17",  "18"
  };

  var result = ChunkBy(testList, 4);  

  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    result.Select(chunk => string.Join(" ", chunk)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Now I got my solution that works for me with the needed requirements :-)